# Como fechar conexão como o JpaRepository e Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Olá,

Estou trabalhando em um projeto usando Spring Boot e estou usando JpaRepository.

E Estou precisando fechar a conexão após executar uma operação no banco, por exemplo: consulta - findAll().

Sei que pode parecer meio estranho, pois o JpaRepository gerencia tudo isso automaticamente, mas o projeto que estou trabalhando necessita realizar algo assim.

Alguém sabe como posso fechar uma conexão manualmente usando o JpaRepository?

Obrigado.

Comment: A primeira pergunta é: por que o projeto necessita fazer isso manualmente? Acho que o requerimento está totalmente errado, a responsabilidade de fechar a conexão depende do pool de conexões, e fechar a conexão manualmente é totalmente não recomendável. Qual a problemática para isso?

Comment: O motivo é q estou num projeto que está usando Multi Tenant e uma das APIs não está querendo mudar de Tenant. Nas outras APIs, o JPA libera as conexões para poder mudar de Tentant, mas nessa API não está acontecendo isso. Por isso queria tentar forçar manualmente a mudança do Tenant. OBS: as APIs que funcionam tem autenticação JWT, essa que não está mudando o Tenant não possui autenticação JWT.

Comment: Entendi, e como requerimento você precisa apenas utilizar `JpaRepository` ou pode fazer as implementações necessárias?